# PROC FREQ multiple 2-way tables with BY statement

Tags: sas

I would like to create multiple 2-way tables stratified by a certain variable.  I would like the order of the printing to be like this:

```
"AxB when strata=1

AxB when strata=2

AxC when strata=1"

etc...

Instead, my code gives me

"AxB when strata=1
AxC when strata=1
AxB when strata=2"
etc...
```

Here is my code:

```
PROC SORT data=mydata;
by riskgroup;
run;

PROC FREQ data=mydata;
by riskgroup;
tables Stent*(RACE INCOME EDUCATION);
run;
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BY` is inherently going to do that, unfortunately (it literally calculates the x1 table first, then the x2 table).

You have options though: both `PROC FREQ` and `PROC TABULATE` have a concept of 'pages', more or less.  Instead of `by` have a third crossing:

So instead of:

```
proc sort data=sashelp.cars out=cars;
  by origin;
run;

proc freq data=cars; 
  by origin;
  table type*(cylinders drivetrain);
run;
```

You want:

```
proc freq data=cars; 
  table origin*type*(cylinders drivetrain);
run;
```

You don't even have to sort first here.

And the equivalent in Tabulate, I like a bit better:

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.cars;
  class Origin Cylinders Type DriveTrain;
  tables origin, Type, Cylinders;
  tables origin, Type, DriveTrain;    
run;
```

Note the multiple `table` statements here, you can do that in either proc and it sometimes looks a bit cleaner especially when doing a 3 level crossing.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use multiple `TABLES` statements.

```
PROC FREQ data=mydata;
  tables riskgroup*Stent*RACE;
  tables riskgroup*Stent*INCOME;
run;
```

If your list of variables is long then write a macro (or other method) to generate the statements.